# Trouble scraping a webpage

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

As background... I know nothing about python and am learning all of this on the fly, but I am trying to scrape the web for fantasy footabll rankings. I have tried beautifulsoup and selenium in python and keep getting stuck because it seems the webpage is running javascript, so when I run the htmlparser, I get back var ecrData instead of a table I can write to csv. Can anyone help me?

```
import requests
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Create a Selenium WebDriver object
driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()

# Navigate to the website
driver.get("https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/rankings/dynasty-overall.php")

# Wait for the page to load
delay=3

# Get the HTML of the page
html = driver.page_source

# Create a Beautiful Soup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Find the table of rankings
table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/section/div/table')
print(len(table))
driver.close()
```

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/section/div/table"}
  (Session info: chrome=xx.xx.xx.xx)
```

Note I have tried by.ID or by.Class - when I use print(soup) it is formatted totally different than when I click inspect element.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You need to post the source of a minimal but *complete* program that demonstrates the error.

Answer (score 0):

More lightweight approach would be to parse the embedded Json data inside the HTML document and create the DataFrame from it. For example:

```py
import re
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/rankings/dynasty-overall.php'

text = requests.get(url).text
data = re.search(r'ecrData = (.*);', text).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data['players'])
print(df.head(10))
```

Prints:

```
   player_id          player_name                         sportsdata_id player_team_id player_position_id player_positions player_short_name player_eligibility player_yahoo_positions                                                  player_page_url          player_filename                                                       player_square_image_url                                                              player_image_url player_yahoo_id cbs_player_id player_bye_week  player_owned_avg  player_owned_espn  player_owned_yahoo player_age  player_ecr_delta  rank_ecr rank_min rank_max rank_ave rank_std pos_rank  tier
0      19236     Justin Jefferson  4131d4ee-0318-4bb5-832a-4dec80668a4f            MIN                 WR               WR      J. Jefferson                 WR                     WR     https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/players/justin-jefferson.php     justin-jefferson.php  https://images.fantasypros.com/images/players/nfl/19236/headshot/210x210.png  https://images.fantasypros.com/images/players/nfl/19236/headshot/210x210.png           32692       2871343              13             100.0               99.9                 100         23               NaN         1        1        5     2.26     1.78      WR1     1
1      23133       Bijan Robinson  f78d68c2-f9da-48e7-b954-26b69efd828d            ATL                 RB               RB       B. Robinson                 RB                     RB       https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/players/bijan-robinson.php       bijan-robinson.php  https://images.fantasypros.com/images/players/nfl/23133/headshot/210x210.png  https://images.fantasypros.com/images/players/nfl/23133/headshot/210x210.png           40055       3168163              11              95.5               92.0                  99         21               NaN         2        1       17     3.34     2.67      RB1     1
2      19788        Ja'Marr Chase  fa99e984-d63b-4ef4-a164-407f68a7eeaf            CIN                 WR               WR          J. Chase                 WR                     WR         https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/players/jamarr-chase.php         jamarr-chase.php  https://images.fantasypros.com/images/players/nfl/19788/headshot/210x210.png  https://images.fantasypros.com/images/players/nfl/19788/headshot/210x210.png           33393       2966320               7              99.9               99.8                 100         23               NaN         3        1        7     3.49     2.26      WR2     1
3      19217      Jonathan Taylor  925195a4-06ba-4e37-ae7d-a3d6a5419139            IND                 RB               RB         J. Taylor                 RB                     RB      https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/players/jonathan-taylor.php      jonathan-taylor.php  https://images.fantasypros.com/images/players/nfl/19217/headshot/210x210.png  https://images.fantasypros.com/images/players/nfl/19217/headshot/210x210.png           32711       2866395              11              99.7               99.4                 100         24               NaN         4        1       17     5.60     4.11      RB2     1
4      19202          CeeDee Lamb  a72ea15b-5199-4101-a300-846e1c655add            DAL                 WR               WR           C. Lamb                 WR                     WR          https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/players/ceedee-lamb.php          ceedee-lamb.php  https://images.fantasypros.com/images/players/nfl/19202/headshot/210x210.png  https://images.fantasypros.com/images/players/nfl/19202/headshot/210x210.png           32687       2865251               7              99.8               99.6                 100         24               NaN         5        3       10     6.40     2.28      WR3     1
5      22982          Breece Hall  db1053d7-3343-43a3-9aab-8353f10f1221            NYJ                 RB               RB           B. Hall                 RB                     RB          https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/players/breece-hall.php          breece-hall.php  https://images.fantasypros.com/images/players/nfl/22982/headshot/210x210.png  https://images.fantasypros.com/images/players/nfl/22982/headshot/210x210.png           33991       3123469               7              98.4               96.7                 100         21               NaN         6        2       21     6.60     4.28      RB3     1
6      18218           A.J. Brown  a9e580f2-1fbe-46fb-887c-c84089b507e4            PHI                 WR               WR        A.J. Brown                 WR                     WR             https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/players/aj-brown.php             aj-brown.php  https://images.fantasypros.com/images/players/nfl/18218/headshot/210x210.png  https://images.fantasypros.com/images/players/nfl/18218/headshot/210x210.png           31883       2258303              10              99.9               99.7                 100         25               NaN         7        4       15     7.89     2.63      WR4     2
7      16393  Christian McCaffrey  f96db0af-5e25-42d1-a07a-49b4e065b364             SF                 RB               RB      C. McCaffrey                 RB                     RB  https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/players/christian-mccaffrey.php  christian-mccaffrey.php  https://images.fantasypros.com/images/players/nfl/16393/headshot/210x210.png  https://images.fantasypros.com/images/players/nfl/16393/headshot/210x210.png           30121       2136743               9              99.9               99.8                 100         26               NaN         8        2       26     8.34     5.30      RB4     2
8      17240       Saquon Barkley  9811b753-347c-467a-b3cb-85937e71e2b9            NYG                 RB               RB        S. Barkley                 RB                     RB       https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/players/saquon-barkley.php       saquon-barkley.php  https://images.fantasypros.com/images/players/nfl/17240/headshot/210x210.png  https://images.fantasypros.com/images/players/nfl/17240/headshot/210x210.png           30972       2185957              13              99.9               99.7                 100         26               NaN         9        4       34    12.40     6.94      RB5     2
9      19790        Jaylen Waddle  0ff9a975-669d-4851-a95d-ab28d9fc29c4            MIA                 WR               WR         J. Waddle                 WR                     WR        https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/players/jaylen-waddle.php        jaylen-waddle.php  https://images.fantasypros.com/images/players/nfl/19790/headshot/210x210.png  https://images.fantasypros.com/images/players/nfl/19790/headshot/210x210.png           33394       2962110              10              99.8               99.6                 100         24               NaN        10        6       25    12.69     4.44      WR5     2
```

Comment: Andrej you are my new favorite human - I am roughly 8 hours into this and you solved it!!

Thank you!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using `requests` is one way. But if your purpose is to *learn selenium*, then here are some suggestions:

1. You set variable `delay`, but never reference it. The best way to wait for an element to appear based on timing is to use the `implicitly_wait` method. Then when you do a find operation on an element, the driver will wait for up to the number of seconds you passed to `implicitly_wait` for the sought element to appear.
2. Since you have processed the page with `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")`, why not search using `BeautifulSoup` ?
3. You might also wish to suppress messages logged by chrome.
4. Use `try/finally` to ensure that if you do get an exception, you still close down the chrome driver.

```py
import requests
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

# Create a Selenium WebDriver object
driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
try:

    # Navigate to the website
    driver.get("https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/rankings/dynasty-overall.php")

    # Wait for up to 3 seconds for elements to appear:
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)

    # Get the HTML of the page
    html = driver.page_source

    # Create a Beautiful Soup object
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    # Find the table of rankings
    # table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/section/div/table')
    table = soup.find("table", {'id': 'ranking-table'})
    rows = table.findChildren('tr', {'class': 'player-row'}) # get all rows
    print(len(rows))
    print(rows[0])
finally:
    driver.close()
```

Prints:

```None
527
<tr class="player-row"><td class="sticky-cell sticky-cell-one">1</td><td class="sticky-cell sticky-cell-two wsis-cell hide-print hide-export"><input aria-label="Toggle Justin Jefferson to compare with other players." class="table-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="[object Object]"/></td><td class=""><div class="player-cell player-cell__td" data-player="19236"><a href="https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/players/justin-jefferson.php">Justin Jefferson</a><span class="player-cell-team">(MIN)</span><!-- --><a class="fp-player-link fp-id-19236 fp-player-name=Justin Jefferson" data-fp-id="19236" href="javascript:;" title="Open player card for Justin Jefferson"></a><div class="fp-icon__container"><a class="fp-icon__link fp-id-19236 gb_loggedout fp-news-icon" data-fp-id="19236" data-fp-index="0" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Open Player Card"><span class="fp-icon__icon"></span></a></div><!-- --><!-- --></div></td><td class="">WR1</td><td class="">13</td><td class="">23</td><td class="matchup-star-cell"><div class="template-stars tooltip-left" data-tooltip="This is an average schedule for Justin Jefferson"><div class="template-stars-star"><div><i class="fa fa-star template-stars-star-filled" tabindex="-1"></i></div><span class="sr-only">3 out of 5 stars</span></div><div class="template-stars-star"><div><i class="fa fa-star template-stars-star-filled" tabindex="-1"></i></div><span class="sr-only">3 out of 5 stars</span></div><div class="template-stars-star"><div><i class="fa fa-star template-stars-star-filled" tabindex="-1"></i></div><span class="sr-only">3 out of 5 stars</span></div><div class="template-stars-star"><div><i class="fa fa-star template-stars-star-empty" tabindex="-1"></i></div><span class="sr-only">3 out of 5 stars</span></div><div class="template-stars-star"><div><i class="fa fa-star template-stars-star-empty" tabindex="-1"></i></div><span class="sr-only">3 out of 5 stars</span></div></div></td><td class=""><div class="tooltip-left ecr-vs-adp-wrap" data-tooltip="Justin Jefferson's ECR matches his ADP" rel="tooltip">0</div></td></tr>
```